# $GLOBALS["argv"] and $argv empty, $_SERVER["argv"] just fine

Tags: php

I am fighting with a (perhaps) simple problem with PHP CLI running on Hostgator shared hosting. A simple code:

```
<?php
var_dump($argv);
var_dump($GLOBALS["argv"]);
var_dump($_SERVER["argv"]);
var_dump(ini_get("register_argv_argv"));
?>
```

When run on my local machine as well as several other instances of php as:

```
php test.php arg1
```

Outputs correctly as predicted:

```
array (
  0 => 'test.php',
  1 => 'arg1'
)
array (
  0 => 'test.php',
  1 => 'arg1'
)
array (
  0 => 'test.php',
  1 => 'arg1'
)
1
```

But run from cron on Hostgator shared hosting it outputs:

```
array (
)
NULL
array (
  0 => 'test.php',
  1 => 'arg1'
)
1
```

The code I am fighting with is a legacy one and that relies heavily upon $GLOBALS["argv"] to parse command line parameters. I have no means to modify the whole codebase to rely on $_SERVER["argv"] instead.

What might be the reason why all my instances of PHP fills all the arrays with commandline parameters, and the hosted php on Hostgator does not populate $GLOBALS["argv"] at all?

I made a workaround to deal with this problem, but I hate when I don't know why something is happening :)

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: It's defined as global `$argv` only when `register_globals` was on.

Comment: Isn't it $_GLOBALS instead of $GLOBALS?

Comment: @Rolice - no it isn't. (it should be, but it isn't -- don't you just wish PHP could be consistent?)

Comment: @mario `register_globals` is *Off* by default and `register_argc_argv` is *On* by default (so `$argv` is normally fully accessible via CLI).

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue, even when toggling the `register_argc_argv` option On/Off (even tested with `register_globals`, just to be safe). The closest I got was that *every* variable, `$argv` `$GLOBALS['argv']` and `$_SERVER['argv']`, were `null` - but you're `$_SERVER['argv']` isn't (very odd). My command was: `php -d register_argc_argv=On test.php arg1`

Comment: @newfurniturey: The CLI SAPI is exempt here, it globalizes those particular variables since 4.3 anyway. See the manual http://php.net/manual/bg/features.commandline.php#~register_argc_argv

Comment: @SDC, no, I don't mean that you think, I just cannot remember, from the time using global variables :D

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with no `$_SERVER['argv'];`

Try `php-cli` instead of `php`:

```
$job = "* * * * * php-cli /home/user/file.php surf";
```

it worked for me!

Comment: genious. I was trying to find a solution for about two weeks. Thank you very much!